# output "get no rate" from grid.py of libsvm

Tags: libsvm

I have downloaded libsvm-3.17 package. Extracted the files. I go to 'tools' folder to try using grid.py to look for suitable c and g with the dataset provided in the package, i.e. heart_scale.
However, the following is what I get

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:...\Documents\libsvm-3.17\tools\grid.py", line 266, in run
    if rate is None: raise RuntimeError('get no rate')
RuntimeError: get no rate
worker local quit.

Can someone help me figure out how to solve this problem.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to scale the data in advance. I got the same problem and it sorted out after I scaled the data. Hope this help.

Comment: This is indeed one of the reasons that caused problem in my case too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you are a newbie in libsvm, I would recommend you to try easy.py instead of grid.py. Secondly, before executing anything you have to compile libsvm, for compiling follow instructions given in README file (You must ensure nmake.exe, cl.exe, link.exe are in system path), here is what it says:

> Windows binaries are in the directory `windows'. To build them via
>   Visual C++, use the following steps:
>
> 1. Open a DOS command box (or Visual Studio Command Prompt) and change to libsvm directory. If environment variables of VC++ have not
>      been set, type
>
>    "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
>
>    You may have to modify the above command according which version of
>      VC++ or where it is installed.
> 2. Type
>
>    nmake -f Makefile.win clean all
> 3. (optional) To build shared library libsvm.dll, type
>
>    nmake -f Makefile.win lib
>
>    Another way is to build them from Visual C++ environment. See details
>      in libsvm FAQ.

Once you have it installed you can start working with easy.py and grid.py.

Comment: Tqvm for your answer. Yes, I had tried easy.py & it works. Do you mean in order to avoid the problem i faced above, even though libsvm-3.17 has folder 'tools' where grid.py are located, I still need to compile libsvm?

Comment: If you take a look to what easy.py does you will see that it executes both grid.py and all binaries from libsvm (svm-train, svm-predict and svm-scale), so that's the reason you need to first compile libsvm.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will try with this and see if it works.

Comment: I had compiled libsvm. When I run grid.py on heart_scale (the dataset that comes together with libsvm-3.17), it still produced the same error output as mentioned in my question above, i.e.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried on both a 64 bit and a 32 bit machine and grid.py works fine.
I have added the default install directories, if your installation directories are different modify accordingly.

Open command prompt and type

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio xx\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat` for 64 bit systems

OR `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio xx\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat` for 32 bit systems.

Navigate to libsvm directory in the same command prompt and run
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio xx\VC\bin\amd64\nmake.exe -f Makefile.win` for 64 bit systems

OR `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio xx\VC\bin\nmake.exe -f Makefile.win` for 32 bit systems

The binaries should be built successfully in the libsvm-3.xx\windows folder

Run grid.py with your options

Within grid.py the gnuplot.exe is usually set at tmp which never worked for me so I changed the gnuplot executable path in my grid.py to the following:

```
self.gnuplot_pathname = r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gnuplot\\bin\\pgnuplot.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the option `-log2p` to run `grid.py`, you will get output `get no rate`. With `grid.py`, you can't use -`log2p` option.(No matches for searching `-log2p` in `grid.py`)
You can use `-log2p` option in [`gridregression.py`](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/gridsvr/gridregression.py).