# Output error from grid.py of libsvm

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I just used the demo data heart_scale from libsvm to test the grid.py, but unfortunately, it always output the same error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "grid.py", line 266, in run
if rate is None: raise RuntimeError('get no rate')
RuntimeError: get no rate
worker local quit.
```

[cmd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ucpc.jpg)

I have tried using different versions of libsvm and gnuplot, but encountered the same error.

```
Versions of libsvms' are : 3.17 and 3.21 
Versions of gnuplots' are : 4.2.6 and 5.0.3
Version of Python : 2.7
```

Also, I have already modified the directories in grid.py,

```
self.svmtrain_pathname = os.path.join(dirname, r'F:\tools\libsvm-master\windows\svm-train.exe')
```

and

```
self.gnuplot_pathname = r'C:\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe'
```

I read some answers in others questions, which still not useful.
Link: [output “get no rate” from grid.py of libsvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643130/output-get-no-rate-from-grid-py-of-libsvm)
[Error from grid.py of libsvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145116/error-from-grid-py-of-libsvm)

Can someone help me figure out how to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and it was easy for me to detect the cause. Hope it is helpful for you.

Try using svm-train directly like `svm-train my_data.txt` and check whether it processes.

I executed this command and found that my input_file (my_data.txt) was wrong. The output prompted me the wrong line of the input_file. I modified it and then it worked.

If it doesn't work, comment me or refer to similar answers like [output "get no rate" from grid.py of libsvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643130/output-get-no-rate-from-grid-py-of-libsvm)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I use different versions of libsvm and gnuplots, which find that the version of gnuplots is too new, so use the old version could finally solve the problem.